# VSCode Extenstion how to get Position of last character of line

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode plugin, and now want to get the position of the last character of a line. Now I want to get it through a known Position object, using "with" method.

The official reference is here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Position

You see "with" method has 2 overloads. Now I want to use the "with(change: {line: number, character:number})" method:

```js
 const endPos = startPos.with({ line: 1, character: -1 });
```

`startPos` is a "Position" object.

But this code is wrong. It seems I misunderstood this method. It just sets the position with the given value, rather than adding the "difference" on it. **So how to get the Position of the last character of one line, derived from a given Position?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the line of the `startPos` and use it's length to get the last char

```
let curLineText = editor.document.lineAt(startPos);
let lastCharPos = new vscode.Position(curLinePos.line, Math.max(curLineText.text.length-1, 0));
```

Remove the `-1` if you want a position after the last character

Comment: Coincidentally, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64562296/836330 which I think is a better solution  ;>}  No math, just properties.