# vscode API: get Position of last character of line

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Following up on [this still unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099341/vscode-extenstion-how-to-get-position-of-last-character-of-line) regarding VS Code Extensions with the [VS Code API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Position). I didn't answer it because it specifically asked for a solution using the `with` method of the `Position` object. I couldn't make that work, nor was I able to loop through the object to get the last character. Trying to manipulate the selection with `vscode.commands.executeCommand` didn't work either, because `vscode.window.activeTextEditor` doesn't appear to reflect the actual selection in the window as soon as the Execution Development Host starts running. The only solution I could find was the hoop-jumping exercise below, which gets the first character of one line and the first character of the next line, sets a Range, gets the text of that Range, then reduces the length of that text string by 1 to get the last character of the previous line.

```
function getCursorPosition() {
  const position = editor.selection.active;
  curPos = selection.start;
  return curPos;
}
curPos = getCursorPosition();
var curLineStart =  new vscode.Position(curPos.line, 0);
var nextLineStart = new vscode.Position(curPos.line + 1, 0);
var rangeWithFirstCharOfNextLine = new vscode.Range( curLineStart, nextLineStart);
var contentWithFirstCharOfNextLine = editor.document.getText(rangeWithFirstCharOfNextLine);
var firstLineLength = contentWithFirstCharOfNextLine.length - 1;
var curLinePos = new vscode.Position(curPos.line, firstLineLength);
var curLineEndPos = curLinePos.character;
console.log('curLineEndPos :>> ' + curLineEndPos);
```

I'm obviously missing something - it can't be impossible to get the last character of a line using the VSCode API without mickey-mousing the thing like this. So the question is simply, what is the *right* way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have the cursor `Position` the `TextDocument.lineAt()` function returns a `TextLine`.  From which you can get its `range` and that `range.end.character` will give you the character number of the last character. - not including the linebreak which if you want to include that see `TextLine.rangeIncludingLineBreak()`.

```
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
const document = editor.document;          
const cursorPos = editor.selection.active;

document.lineAt(cursorPos).range.end.character;
```

Note (from `[TextDocument.lineAt documentation][1]` ):

> Returns a text line denoted by the position. Note that the returned
> object is not live and changes to the document are not reflected.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark, that is the bridge I was looking for but didn't know where to look.

Comment: @VanAlbert If you think this answers your question, you should mark it as accepted. :)